# EXCEL;How to list the numbers in several ranges

Tags: excel, list, range

I have a log list of ranges in excel. 
I want to compare these ranges to an even longer list of numbers. as I need to find each number that's missing, I assume I need to change my list of ranges to a list of numbers. Myy list containts about 12000 ranges, so manually is not an option
My ranges does not form a continuos range, so I cannot just create from lowest number to highest

Example list of ranges
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmiKq.png)

Edited to hopefully explain the problem. I have a list of ranges. Range 1 is from 1-3, range 2 from 24-26, range 3 from 345-456. 
I want to create a single list, containing all numbers in my ranges these..i.e : 1,2,3,24,25,26,345,346,347,348...

Comment: I think if you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can edit your question to provide a clearer example of what you need and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood what you want, this may work for you:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$6,1,0),"Not in To List")
```

Which repeats the number for a match and a message if not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I may have explained this unclearly :( I need to create a single list containing all numbers in my ranges. So a list with all numbers between my fromlist - tolist. so a range with 1-2-3-24-25-26...

Comment: So, show a sheet showing source ranges and a precise result range... In my example I used the numbers in the "from list" to see if they were in the "to list"...

Comment: So if you copy all the different ranges into a new sheet in one single column then select all the numbers and click on the "remove duplicates" (Data Tab) you will have a list of the unique numbers.